# Are there current benchmarks for algorithms solving Travelling Salesman?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, efficiency, traveling-salesman

I'm researching the travelling salesman problem and looking for data regarding the current state of affairs regarding solutions and performance. So far the only data I've states that the current record for optimality is held by 'Concorde' which found a solution for a graph containing 85,900 cities. I've also found [benchmarking data for Concorde](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/benchmarks/bench.html), as well as [data pertaining to the current best performance for a world map](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/index.html).

Is this data still accurate? It looks like a lot of this hasn't been updated since the early 2000s.

Comment: I don't think that asking for a summary of the state of the art in TSP solvers is a very broad question so I disagree with the close vote.

Comment: What do you mean by "accurate"? The data, the timings, or which is the best algorithm *today*?

Comment: @Raphael all I really need to know for now is whether or not the current record for optimality is still 85,900 cities and whether or not the information on the current best performance for the world map is current. Also, is there a ruling body for this sort of thing?

Comment: Ten years later, it's be surprising if that was the record. Sheer increase in computational power is likely to beat that, even without algorithmic improvements. *If* anybody bothers to perform and publish benchmarks.

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you done a literature search?  Have you looked for papers that discuss the Concorde result, and then used Google Scholar to find every paper that cites them?  That seems like the obvious place to start.

Comment: @DW given the popularity of the problem I'd hoped there was a ready-answer to my question that didn't require me to do a full lit-review. obviously I'm going to have to do one at some point as I plan on submitting my findings to a peer-reviewed journal. for now, though, I'm just looking to set up some (admittedly lofty) goals for the project. what I've done thus far (beyond googling) is scan through the journal databases to ensure my approach hasn't been tried (it hasn't).

Comment: @DW 'the project' is my endeavour to create a better TSP algorithm than what's currently available.

Comment: afaik planar/euclidean TSP has seen some very fast algorithms in recent times. are you talking about non euclidean TSP or euclidean?

Comment: My 2 cents for your own benchmark. Starting with an instance, you can easily derive a new instance with the same size but much harder for Concorde to solve; it may require a computation time up to 30,000 times more greater than what was needed to Concorde to solve the original instance. See this paper:  Farhan Ahammed, Pablo Moscato: Evolving L-Systems as an Intelligent Design Approach to Find Classes of Difficult-to-Solve Traveling Salesman Problem Instances. EvoApplications (1) 2011: 1-11

Comment: So, if you want to design an algorithm that outperforms Concorde, try designing an algorithm able to solve one of the difficult instances (generated using the approach described in the paper) in the same time Concorde solves the easy instance used to seed the generation process. If you succeed, your algorithm may well become the state of the art. Of course, your algorithm should also beat Concorde on the easy instances as well!

Comment: @MassimoCafaro - thx I'll definitely check out that paper!

Answer (score -1):

TSP has many variants under study eg Euclidean vs noneuclidean, exact vs approximations, interrelated but also at times separate threads of research. heres a recent nontechnical survey from early 2013 on TSP by an expert mathematical writer Klarreich, [Computer Scientists Take Road Less Traveled](http://www.simonsfoundation.org/quanta/20130129-computer-scientists-take-road-less-traveled/) that sheds some insight on recent improvements/ theoretical advances & can be mined for some refs. an old approximation algorithm by 1976 Christofides has been unrivalled for decades but some minor theoretical improvements have been made recently. as indicated in the article some theoretical TSP research that is not nec (practically) implemented veers into what is referred to as [Galactic algorithm](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/galactic-algorithms/) territory by expert RJ Lipton.

as a more applied resource/ angle, also a leading group/ site for benchmarking is [DIMACS](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/), NSF center for discrete math & CS, which also has a [TSP page with algorithms/ benchmarks](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Challenges/TSP/) updated 2013.

Comment: Being myself incompetent on this topic, I would appreciate it if downvoters would explain what is wrong with this answer, so that I might have a chance to learn something.

Comment: @babou I guess because most of the answer is a digression on algorithms to solve TSP, unrelated to the question, and written in a way to maximize legibility to boot. Only the last sentence is relevant, and it's only a couple of links. The links (with proper identification) technically are enough here because the question is calling for resources, which makes this an answer but a low-quality one.

Comment: the question is not narrowly written. the answer responds in a correspondingly not-narrow way. DR interprets the question is asking for some summary in the state of the art TSP solvers. am eagerly awaiting reading any superior answer rather than vague/ unconstructive criticism of this one.

Comment: @vzn thank you for your reply! yes or no - is the current TSP record still held by Concorde for solving to optimality a graph containing 85,900?

Comment: DD glad you found something useful. unfortunately its not a black or white issue as the DIMACS pg reveals. it depends on what algorithmic category is chosen and what degree of approximation vs exact results are acceptable etc.; Concorde is defn a leader as listed in the results page. some of these questions are answered by competition results. unf the latest DIMACS competition for TSP apparently was from ~2002. here is another slide show by [Johnson](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Challenges/TSP/ismp.pdf) summarizing the results.

Comment: @vzn I think there's been a miscommunication. Wikipedia states: 

_In April 2006 an instance with 85,900 points was solved using Concorde TSP Solver, taking over 136 CPU-years, see Applegate et al. (2006)._ 

Is 85,900 currently the largest graph that has been solved to optimality by an algorithm?

Comment: DD it would have been helpful if you cited that info in your original question. "In 2006, Cook and others computed an optimal tour through an 85,900-city instance given by a microchip layout problem, currently the largest solved TSPLIB instance." [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) / wikipedia. that is the largest known instance according to the wikipedia page, but there do not seem to be recent international TSP competitions, which help make visible/ validate/ measure these types of milestones. possibly larger instances have been solved and not publicly reported.

Comment: @vzn sorry about that, as a new user I was only authorized to post two links in my question - figured the wikipedia link was the one of the least value to the community so i left it off. if you can repost your comment in the form of an answer, I'll accept it.